# The meaning of 'natural ordering' and its relation to the compareTo() method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, interface, implementation

While reviewing the topic of arrays in Java, I came across the following method in the `Arrays` class of the `java.util` package.

```
void sort(type[] array)
```

Further, I stumbled upon something, which I felt begged for more explanation.

> The method sorts the elements in the array according to their
>   **natural ordering**.

I try to sum up my doubts on this below:

- What is meant precisely by **natural ordering**?
- Does **natural ordering** of primitives and reference types differ and if so how?
- Lastly, how does `compareTo()` method of the `Comparable<T>` interface defines and/or overrides **natural  ordering**?

Comment: _Natural ordering_ is just the nomenclature used by Java to express the ordering imposed by `Comparable<T>` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is meant precisely by natural ordering?

Natural ordering is the ordering defined by `compareTo` of a `Comparable`. For example, `Integer`s are naturally ordered from lowest to highest value.

> `Does natural ordering of primitives and reference types differ and if so how?

Technically, no. The natural ordering of primitives (`double`, `boolean` is the same order as those of their wrapper classes (`Double`, `Boolean`).

> How does `compareTo()` method of the `Comparable` interface define and/or override natural ordering?

`compareTo` defines the natural ordering of a class, which is why the Javadoc explains, "All elements in the array must implement the Comparable interface."

As a side note, natural ordering is overriden by defining a `Comparator` for cases where ordering is performed. For example, you can sort a `String[]` however you want by using `Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)` (The generic `T` would become `String` in this case).

Answer (score 3):

We talk about **natural ordering** when we sort instances of a class that extends `Comparable` thanks to the implementation of [`compareTo(T o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-).

Check the javadoc of [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class
>   that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's
>   **natural ordering**, and the class's `compareTo` method is referred to as its *natural comparison* method.